# Passing Related Row to Django Database Function

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset

Is it possible to pass rows of related fields into django database functions and if so how can i accomplish this? When I try, I end up getting an integer (the id column) instead of the row.

Models:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    pass


class ModelB(models.Model):
    pass


class ModelC(models.Model):
    model_a_rel = models.ManyToManyField(
        ModelA, 
        related_name='m2mrelatedobj'
    )
    fkobj = models.ForeignKey(
        ModelB
    )
```

Desired Queryset:

```
ModelA.objects.annotate(
    my_annotation=DatabaseFn('m2mrelatedobj__model_a_rel')
).filter(my_annotation=True)
```

My goal is to pass **rows** of `fkobj` into `DatabaseFn` so that the join is done once over the queryset and not inside each annotation.

Is this even possible in django? Right now, I get an error from my postgres function saying that it received an integer instead of a row, which communicates that django is not doing the additional join. Any insight would be much appreciated, thanks.

**environment**: `Django v1.10.3, python 2.7, postgresql 9.5`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for the underscore notation. Something like this:

```
ModelC.objects.all().values('model_a_rel__field_ModelA1_name','model_a_rel__field_ModelA2_name','fkobj__ModelB1_field_name')
```

Or the other way around:

```
ModelA.objects.all().values('m2mrelatedobj__ModelC1_field_name')
```

Those queries are one round trip to database. In the foreign key case, it will return one line with desired columns. In the many to many case, it will return one line for each existing relation with the columns you chose with underscore notation.

I hop this helps

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this is the syntax I show in my example that isn't working. The problem is that i don't want to enumerate every column (as in your second example), and i want foreign key related objects of the m2m related object. Your solution will yield fields of the m2m object or fields of the fk object

Comment: I see. I'd be very interested in an answer that doesn't need to enumerate all columns too. Waiting for that here ;). For the second remark you can keep doing double underscore to get fk related to m2m object: ModelA.objects.all().values('m2mrelatedobj__ModelC1_FK_name__FK_filed_name').  Cheers!